# What is the difference between map and mapTo in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to understand the difference between map and mapTo in Kotlin. What is the difference using some examples?

Comment: From the doc: [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html): Applies the given transform function to each element of the original array and appends the results to the given destination. On the other hand `map`: Returns a list containing the results of applying the given transform function to each element in the original array.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) creates a new list internally, and puts its results into that list, then it returns that list:

```
val mapResult = listOf(1, 2, 3).map { it * 2 } // you get a new list instance returned
```

---

If you use [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html) instead, you can specify the destination where it places the mapped elements, by providing your own list as the first parameter:

```
val myList = ArrayList<Int>()
val mapToResult = listOf(1, 2, 3).mapTo(myList) { it * 2 }
```

If the list you're provided already has elements in it, those will be kept, and the new ones will be added to those. It also returns the destination list for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

**map:**  map can transform your data(List) and can return either complete modified list or List of a variable of model, for ex:

You have a model:

```
data class Student(var id:String, var name:String, var className:String)
```

Now from arrayOfStudent, we want all the name of students in capital letters, so apply map like this:

```
val listOfNamesInCapitalLetters= arrStudent.map {
            it.name= it.name.toUpperCase()
        }
Log.d("map_test", "student's name: $listOfNamesInCapitalLetters")
```

The output will be:

```
[AMIT, VIJAY, SUMIT, KARAN, SMAEER]
```

---

Now, what if you want the whole student list, with name in capital letters and className is increased by 1, let's do this:

```
val result= arrStudent.map {
            it.name= it.name.toUpperCase()       // transforming name to upper case
            it.className=it.className+1          // increasing class by 1
            it           // <- Note that we return it, because list will be prepared of the object which is returned by last statement of map
        }

Log.d("modified_list", result.toString())
```

The output will be:

```
[Student(id=1, name=AMIT, className=6), Student(id=2, name=VIJAY, className=7), Student(id=3, name=KARAN, className=8), Student(id=4, name=VIRAT, className=9), Student(id=5, name=SAM, className=10)]
```

---

---

**mapTo**: If you want to transform your list into a different type of list then use mapTo, for example, we have a different data class named: CompactStudent

```
data class CompactStudent(val id:String, val name:String)
```

Now if we want to convert List to List, note that `CompactStudent` contains `id` and `name` but not the `className` as compared to `Student` model, so to do this:

```
 val arrayList=ArrayList<CompactStudent>()

        arrStudent.mapTo(arrayList){
            CompactStudent(it.id,it.name)
        }
Log.d("studentCompact", arrayList.toString())
```

Output will be:

```
[StudentCompct(id=1, name=AMIT), StudentCompct(id=2, name=VIJAY), StudentCompct(id=3, name=KARAN), StudentCompct(id=4, name=VIRAT), StudentCompct(id=5, name=SAM)]
```